how to select 3 max dates with on multiple IDs
If I have a table with multiple customer IDs, and each customer has orders on different dates, I need to select each customer and their last 3 orders with their dates.



Customer
Order_ID
Date
Time
Status
CreatedBy




A
1
9/29/2021
2359
1
john


A
2
9/29/2021
1028
1
john


A
3
1/19/2021
0000
2
john


A
4
01/18/2021
2359
2
adam


A
5
01/18/2021
0828
2
adam


B
6
9/29/2021
2359
2
john


B
7
9/28/2019
1028
1
adam


B
8
1/19/2023
0300
2
john


B
9
1/15/2020
0000
2
john


B
10
1/10/2017
0000
1
john


C
11
1/18/2024
0000
1
adam



Result should be like below (need also to select order in status 2 and created by john)



Customer
Order_ID
Date
Time




A
1
9/29/2021
2359


A
2
9/29/2021
1028


A
3
1/19/2021
0000


B
8
1/19/2023
0300


B
6
9/29/2021
2359


B
9
1/15/2020
0000



not getting anywhere with max function while grouping
SELECT 
    tt.* 
FROM 
    orders tt 
INNER JOIN     
    (SELECT 
         order_id, MAX(date) AS MaxDateTime     
     FROM 
         order 
     WHERE
         status = '2' AND createdby = 'john'     
     GROUP BY  
         order_id) groupedtt ON tt.order_id = groupedtt.order_id  
                             AND tt.date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime

Result should like this
